# What is CvMatchShapes returning?

Tags: java, c++, image-processing, opencv, javacv

I have these two images.

[image: small size]

And...
[image: larger size]

I made them into graysclae images and then passed the two images to `cvMatchImages`like so

```
Double someValue = cvMatchShapes(grayImage, grayImage2, CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I2, 0);
    System.out.println(someValue);
```

The value that was printed by sysout was 1.465496453484283. What is this value representing? How can i use it to match other images and also how can I reject those that do not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the value means how different the two objects are,it represents the Hu moment feature distance between the two shapes. the smaller it is ,more similar the two objects are.
A threshold can be used to perform the match like this: if output value is smaller than the threshold, two objects match, or the two objects differ.
As to how to choose a threshold, it depends .
you can use some instances to train the threshold.
I strongly advise you to normalize objects in images to similar size.this will give you better accuracy

Comment: So the value that is being returned is a factor of translation?

Comment: if these images were of same size what value will be returned? 0?

Comment: You can say that, but it is a distance between features of the two objects, the distance may be Euclidian distance or something similar

Comment: if input images were same , 0 should be returned , which means absolutely similar, i.e. the same

Comment: I have tested the function,if two images were exactly the same , 0 will be returned.By the way, taken the two images you posted as input, cvMatchShapes outputs 0.001815 in my demo.

Comment: did you use grayscale images or these exact images?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9226/discussion-between-prometheus87-and-zhijie)

Comment: the input image should be grayscale, in fact it will be binary during the process of cvMatchShapes

Comment: It's interesting why OpenCV docs miss even this short description of cvMatchShapes function and its return value.